# what's -Dcom.sun.javafx.virtualKeyboard=javafx other values

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

in JAVAFX i want to use windows virtual keyboard instead of JAVAFX virtual keyboard in touch screen whats the true setting or whats the true value to the property

```
-Dcom.sun.javafx.virtualKeyboard=javafx
```

Comment: Do you want to show virtuel keyBoard from JavaFx application or integrate this keyboad in your application?

Comment: i am write in Arabic Language layout and JavaFx built in virtual keyboard support English layout only . so i want windows virtual keyboard to open when user focus on TextField automaticaty

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open windows virtual keyboard when user focus on textfield ,you can do that by call `osk.exe` from the root:

```
  userInputField.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                String sysroot = System.getenv("SystemRoot");
                try {
                    Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(sysroot + "/system32/osk.exe");
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(LoginController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        });
```